# Where is Hibernate Session Opened/Closed in a Spring Boot App?

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa

I have a Spring Boot project which uses hibernate via the JPA API. I would like to know where a hibernate session is opened/closed in such a project.

- Does spring open a session at the beginning of a `@Transactional` annotated method and close the session at the end of the method? If not, when exactly does hibernate session opening/closing happen?
- Is there a way to keep the current session after a `@Transactional` method has returned? For example to lazy load collections outside a `@Transactional` method?

Please note that I am not necessarily talking about a web project. It can be any kind of project.

Comment: Basically never... As an `EntityManager` is opened. Spring Boot by default keeps the `EntityManager` op due to the registration of the `OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter` by the framework.

Comment: @M.Deinum shouldn't that be closed when the request is done? And also what if that is set to `false`; will that mean that the session is closed after the `@Transactional` method?

Comment: @M.Deinum but then all code runs within the scope of the session? In that case, there would never be an `org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException`?

Comment: If you have set that to false there will be no `Entitymanager` left after the transaction leading to lazy init exceptions. If it is kept open (and you are n't reusing objects over threads/requests) you won't get those exceptions.

Comment: The pitfall to the `OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter` is that people often don't realize that if they modify their entity in the controller after it has been returned, then the change gets persisted.  It also means that you keep your database connections open longer than necessary, which could lead to performance problems if your application uses heavy rendering techniques or heavy controller logic.  It's viewed as an anti-pattern and really shouldn't be used.

Comment: The persisting of entities isn't true as it depends on the flush mode you have set and (if I recall correctly) Spring sets it by default to a value that will only trigger on a transaction commit. (Also you shouldn't be changing that stuff in a controller to begin with). Regarding the connection claim that is true. Although considered by some as an anti pattern I have used it successfully in several high traffic applications without issues.